# Problema com jogo da forca

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando criar um jogo da forca. O jogo em si está quase pronto.

O problema se encontra na hora dele checar a se a letra é igual a digitada. Eu chequei se a letra estava igual e caso não estivesse ele dava um valor a variável de controle e dependendo do valor ele tirava 1 das chances(jogadas), porém mesmo acertando ele continua tirando 1 da jogada.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jogo da Forca</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var palavra=new Array();
        var controlando=0;
        var cont=0;
        var tracos=[];
        var conpt=0;//controle
        var jogadas=5;
function preencher (valor){
        var elemento = document.getElementById("tela");
        var value= elemento.value;
        if (controlando==0){
             elemento.value=value+valor;

        }
        if(controlando==1){
            preenchimento(valor);
            alert(jogadas);

                }}

}
function preenchimento(valor){
            var elemento = document.getElementById("resp");
               var value= elemento.value;
                var checando=0;
            for(var i=0; i<palavra.length;i++){
               if (valor == palavra[i]){
                   tracos[i]=valor;
                   document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
                    conpt=2;
               }
                else 
                    conpt=1;
            }
    if (conpt==1)
        jogadas=jogadas-1;




               elemento.value=tracos;


    }



function backspace(campo) {
    valor = campo.value;
    tamanho = valor.length
    campo.value = valor.substring(0, tamanho-1)
        }
function iniciar(tela){
        var copia= tela.value;
        document.getElementById("tela").disabled = 1; //checar se pode
        palavra=copia;
        controlando=1;
        criarTracos();
    }
function criarTracos(valor){
            var elemento = document.getElementById("resp");
            var tam = palavra.length;
            for (var i=0; i<tam;i++)
            {tracos[i]="__";}
             elemento.value=tracos;

            }



    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVp232wRQyE&index=17&list=UUezdgg4HLLhPwGKNfJzaBww
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="all" >
<h1>JOGO DA FORCA</h1>

    <div id="campo">
        Palavra: <input type="password" id="tela" value=""/>
    </div>
      <input type="text" id="resp" value="" onload="criarTracos();"/>
    <div id="teclas">
        <br/>
                <input type="button" value="Q" id="Q" onClick="preencher(value);" >
                <input type="button" value="W" id="W" onClick="preencher(value);"   >
                <input type="button" value="E" id="E" onClick="preencher(value);" >
                <input type="button" value="R" id="R" onClick="preencher(value);"  >
                <input type="button" value="T" id="T" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="Y" id="Y" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="U" id="U" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="I" id="I" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="O" id="P" onClick="preencher(value);">

        <br/>
                <input type="button" value="A" id="A" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="S" id="S" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="D" id="D" onClick="preencher(value);" >
                <input type="button" value="F" id="F" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="G" id="G" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="H" id="H" onClick="preencher(value);" >
                <input type="button" value="J" id="J" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="K" id="K" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="L" id="L" onClick="preencher(value);">

        <br />
                <input type="button" value="Z" id="Z" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="X"id="X" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="C" id="C" onClick="preencher(value);" >
                <input type="button" value="V" id="V" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="B" id="B" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="N" id="N" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="M" id="M" onClick="preencher(value);" >
        <input type="button" value="APAGAR" id="APAGAR" onClick="backspace(tela);" style="width=1000px;">
        <br/>
     </div>
     <br />
 <input type="button"  value="iniciar" id="iniciar" onClick="iniciar(tela);" >
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que é a variável `renan`?

Comment: Você não disse o que está errado.

Comment: O que exatamente está dando errado? tente usar o [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) para mostrar o que está dando errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deixa eu reformatar o seu javascript:

```javascript
    var palavra = new Array();
    var controlando = 0;
    var cont = 0;
    var tracos = [];
    var conpt = 0; // controle
    var jogadas = 5;

    function preencher(valor) {
        var elemento = document.getElementById("tela");
        var value = elemento.value;
        if (controlando == 0) {
            elemento.value = value + valor;
        }
        if (controlando == 1) {
            preenchimento(valor);
            alert(jogadas);
        }
    }

} // ESTE DAQUI ESTÁ SOBRANDO

function preenchimento(valor) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("resp");
    var value = elemento.value;
    var checando = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
        if (valor == palavra[i]) {
            tracos[i] = valor;
            document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
            conpt = 2;
        }
        else 
            conpt = 1;
    }

    if (conpt == 1)
        jogadas = jogadas - 1;

    elemento.value = tracos;
}

function backspace(campo) {
    valor = campo.value;
    tamanho = valor.length // Faltou o ponto-e-vírgula.
    campo.value = valor.substring(0, tamanho - 1) // Faltou o ponto-e-vírgula.
}

function iniciar(tela) {
    var copia = tela.value;
    document.getElementById("tela").disabled = 1; //checar se pode
    palavra = copia;
    controlando = 1;
    criarTracos();
}

function criarTracos(valor) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("resp");
    var tam = palavra.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        tracos[i] = "__";
    }
    elemento.value = tracos;
}
```

Me parece que você simplesmente se perdeu na hora de ver o que está abrindo e o que está fechando, e por causa disso o seu programa não funciona direito porque há algo que não está fechando aonde deveria. Ou algum código que você pensou que colocou dentro de alguma função, mas na verdade colocou fora.

No seu exemplo há um fecha-chave que não abre em lugar nenhum. Como o seu código está uma total bagunça devido a falta de identação, fica difícil perceber isso.

Então, aqui vão as dicas:

- Idente o seu código adequadamente. Só de fazer isso, já deve ficar claro quais são os seus erros.
- Sempre use as chaves em blocos `if`, `else`, `for`, `while` e `do-while`, senão você vai se perder facinho.

Mas o seu grande problema é aqui:

```javascript
for (var i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
    if (valor == palavra[i]) {
        tracos[i] = valor;
        document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
        conpt = 2;
    }
    else 
        conpt = 1;
}

if (conpt == 1)
    jogadas = jogadas - 1;
```

Observe que ele define o `conpt` com 2 sempre que a letra está correta e 1 quando está incorreta. Ou seja, se houve uma letra correta, mas depois uma incorreta, o valor vai acabar sendo 1! E aí que está o erro, isso significa que apenas a última letra importa.

Vamos arrumar isso:

```javascript
var conpt = false;
for (var i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
    if (valor == palavra[i]) {
        tracos[i] = valor;
        document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
        conpt = true;
    }
}

if (!conpt)
    jogadas = jogadas - 1;
```

E então você retira o `var conpt = 0;` que está lá no começo, pois você já o está declarando e usando apenas dentro da função `preenchimento`.